# How to identify the latest stable REST API version of Azure DevOps Services?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-artifacts

In my project, there is a requirement to create Azure artifacts feed automatically.

For this I used REST API mentioned in this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/feed%20%20management/create%20feed?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

and used python to create feed.

POST [https://feeds.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/packaging/feeds?api-version=5.0-preview.1](https://feeds.dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/_apis/packaging/feeds?api-version=5.0-preview.1)
It worked fine.

Later I saw that a new version of API was available.
It is not easy to change the code every time there is a new API version.
So the question is how to identify/use the latest stable working version of API always?

Comment: The versions don't go anywhere or stop working in general.  If you build it against a version, it should continue to work unless they make any very major adjustments to the architecture (deprecate the corresponding functionality).

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, there wasn't  a hint if there is a new Rest API version released. But just like Matt commented, the old version will not stop working in general. It's quite stable.

Azure DevOps and Team Foundation Server REST APIs are versioned to **ensure applications and services continue to work** as APIs evolve.

[image]

Major API version releases align with Team Foundation Server RTM releases. For example, the 3.0 API set was introduced with Team Foundation Server 2017.

You'll find a quick mapping of REST API versions and their corresponding TFS releases [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#api-and-tfs-version-mapping). All API versions will work on the server version mentioned as well as later versions.

Unlike Azure DevOps Server/TFS, if you are working on Azure DevOps Service, you do not have to pay too much attention which version you are using.  It's supported on 1.0~6.0.

Hope it is clearly.